# Procedure Regist_Update Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Regist_Update, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

```
use DBRegist
UPDATE Regist
SET Regist.Major = upload.Major
FROM Regist
    INNER JOIN upload
    ON Regist.Reg_ID = upload.ID
WHERE Regist.Period='2018' or Regist.Period='2017' or Regist.Period='2016'
```

Comment: please post the trigger `Regist_Update` query

Comment: Squirrel is almost certainly correct. The problem is not with this statement but with a poorly-written trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Upload table is returning more than one row per ID. you can make sure to get only one row per ID, so that it does not affect update. I just ordered by major, you can order by any one of them as per your requirement. Also, you can give between instead of giving or clause, I changed that in your where condition as well.

```
use DBRegist
UPDATE Regist
SET Regist.Major = upload.Major
FROM Regist
    INNER JOIN (select ID, major, row_number() over (partition by ID order by major) rownum from  upload) upload

    ON Regist.Reg_ID = upload.ID and upload.rownum = 1 
WHERE Regist.Period between '2016' and '2018'
```

Comment: I think table regist have more than one row per Reg_ID. Not table upload. couse I have updated table upload in another table. and work. but if I updated in table regist, it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to using an updatable CTE, you might not have to change your logic at all:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT r.Major, u.Major AS MajorSource
    FROM Regist r
    INNER JOIN upload u
        ON r.Reg_ID = u.ID
    WHERE r.Period = IN ('2016', '2017', '2018')
)

UPDATE cte
SET Major = MajorSource;
```

Comment: I dont undertand what it this. but it still not work. error show like this "Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
The multi-part identifier "Regist.Period" could not be bound."

Comment: @AgaYanu You're not running my code, because `Regist.Period` does not appear anywhere in my answer.  Try my actual answer please.

Comment: can i get solution without using CTE?